# Add one entity with oneToMany and other entity link

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-forms

I have three entity :

- A > oneToMany B
- B > ManyToOne C

And I want to add A with many B (the B list is all C title)

**Entity A :**

```
class A
{

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="B", mappedBy="a", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $listeB;

public function addB(B $b)
{
    $this->listeB[] = $b;
    $b->setA($this);
    return $this;
}

}
```

**Entity B :**

```
class B
{  

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="A", inversedBy="listeB")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $a;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="C")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $c;

}
```

**Entity C :**

```
class C
{
/*
Classic, just have "title"
 * 
 */
}
```

How to A form ?

```
$builder->add('listeB', 'entity', array(
'class' => 'B',
'label' => 'Liste de B',
'expanded' => true,
'multiple' => true
));
```

Is empty, and wrong because I want checkbox list of C (for add in B).

Comment: If is empty can be because the relations are not well setted or you dont have already any persisted data of B, for the checkbox part you need to override the default symfony theme for multiple select.